# Controlling margin around PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, manipulate, legending

Here's my code:

```
k = 1; 
L = 1; 
λ[n_] = (((2*n - 1)*Pi)/(2*L))^2; 
v[x_] = -50*x + 100; 
f[x_] = (300*x*Cos[11*x] + 100)*(1 - x); 
b[n_] = (2/L)*Integrate[(f[x] - v[x])*Sin[Sqrt[λ[n]]*x], {x, 0, L}]; 
w[x_, t_] = Sum[b[i]*Sin[Sqrt[λ[i]]*x]*Exp[(-λ[i])*k*t], {i, 1, 5}]; 
u[x_, t_] = v[x] + w[x, t];

Manipulate[Plot[{u[x, t], f[x], v[x]}, {x, 0, L}, 
     PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red}}, 
     AxesLabel -> {x, u}, PlotRange -> {-30, 120}, 
     PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], {t, 0, .5}]
```

Note how the right edge of the box of the output jumps back and forth depending on how many decimal places is shown for a specific $t$ value. How can I anchor that right edge so it doesn't move back and forth?

Comment: Please don't use styled formatting and subscript boxes if those are not necessary to the problem at hand (as in this case). It makes it extremely hard to read the question. Use `InputForm` instead

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean: I just copied and pasted my code. How do I do what you are suggesting without retyping those parts of my code?

Comment: I meant that stuff like `\*SubsuperscriptBox[...` is very hard to read if I don't have mma with me to copy-paste into the FE. You could do `InputForm[Hold[stuff goes here]]` and copy-paste everything inside the `Hold[output here]`

Comment: Gotcha. Just didn't know about that, but I will use it henceforth.

Comment: Better now than tomorrow! I did it for you this time :)

Comment: Alternatively, right click on the Cell and select Convert to -> Raw InputForm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is to replace `"Expressions"` with the more controllable `LineLegend["Expressions"]` as you can pass in options, such as [`LegendFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LegendFunction.html):

```
PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions",
  LegendFunction -> (Pane[#, ImageSize -> {100, 100}] &)]
```

[image]

and for a higher value of `t`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need.